# Designer collaboration with RTC

Tags: dreamweaver, collaboration, rtc

I'm a designer working in a software development shop that uses Rational Team Concert. Back when we were using SubVersion, I could use Dreamweaver to make my CSS edits and everything played nice.

I'm doing fine with Visual Studio's RTC client for our .NET projects, but I'm at a loss on how to effectively collaborate on our Java projects. There doesn't seem to be an RTC client for Dreamweaver and I'm beating my head against a wall trying to get MyEclipse to play nice.

How do your designers/developers collaborate in RTC?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding MyEclipse, check on which version of Eclipse it is based on:

- the latest MyEclipse10 is based on Indigo (Eclipse 3.7).
- but [this thread](https://jazz.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=70987) mentions that "RTC 3.0.1 supports Eclipse SDK 3.5.2, 3.6 and 3.6.1"

So depending the version of MyEclipse you choose, you might have some issue making the integration of RTC works properly in it.

[Another solution would be to choose an](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php) Eclipse distro with [WST (web standard tools)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/main.php) in it, and browse the [WTP (Web Tools Platform)](http://eclipse.org/webtools/) project to make sure the CSS editor is added to your chosen Eclipse package.
And then, install the RTC plugin in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help -- I'm going to try both MyEclipse and the regular Eclipse suggestion you had here to see which will work better. Getting the P2 installation was key to getting any forward momentum.

Answer (score 1):

You should install RTC into MyEclipse. You can do that by grabbing the p2 download from the [download page](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/3.0.1.2?p=allDownloads), then opening Help->"Install New Software..." and adding the zip file as a repository.

Starting with RTC 4.0 [there will be integration with the Windows shell](https://jazz.net/blog/index.php/2012/02/06/introducing-the-rational-team-concert-shell-integration-for-windows-explorer/), so your life should get much easier.

Comment: But the latest version of MyEclipse isn't based on a supported Eclipse for RTC3.x, right? RTC3.x only supports Eclipse3.6.x, not 3.7 yet. (RTC4 will, I suppose)

Comment: I'm using a milestone build of RTC4 on Eclipse 3.7. Works for me. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help -- the P2 installation was the key. Still working things out, but it's better.